# Javascript HTML5 Geolocation bug?

Tags: javascript, compass-geolocation

```
function getMyLocation() {
if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
}
else{
    alert("Geolocation not supported"); 
}
}

var user_lat;
var user_long;
var d_long;
var d_lat;

function displayLocation(position) { 
user_lat    = position.coords.latitude;
user_long   = position.coords.longitude; 
alert( "you are at lat: " + user_lat + " ,longitude: " + user_long);
 }

function getLocationDestination() {
var e = document.getElementById("building");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

alert("you want to go to " +  strUser + " and the cords are " + building_array[strUser]); 

getMyLocation();
alert("heelo");
displayLocation(position);
alert("heelo");
displayLocation(position);
}
```

The code is pretty simple but when I run geoLocationDestination(), I don’t get a second alert from displayLocation(position) not even in a while loop that runs it 20 times. The program exits after the second hello? Any ideas?

Comment: It seems `position` is undefined in `getLocationDestination()`...

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, i get position is undefined in displaylocation function, this is because you need to call this function from getMyLocation and not seperately passing position parameter,
below is a working code,

```
<html>
<script>
function getMyLocation() {
if(navigator.geolocation){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
}
else{
alert("Geolocation not supported"); 
}
}

 var user_lat;
 var user_long;
 var d_long;
 var d_lat;

function displayLocation(position) { 


 user_lat    = position.coords.latitude;
 user_long   = position.coords.longitude; 
 alert( "you are at lat: " + user_lat + " ,longitude: " + user_long);
 }

function getLocationDestination() {
var sel = document.getElementById("foo");
var option = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
var text = option.text;
var value = option.value;
alert(text, value);

getMyLocation();

}

</script>
<input type="submit" id=hello onclick=getLocationDestination();>   
<select id="foo">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
 </select>

 </html>
```

This code displays selected value from select box and gives alert(i suppose it is "you want to go" part of your coding,Im not sure of this as you ahve not included the HTML part),
then alerts the latitude and longitude